# LINQ to XML Sum Child Nodes in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, xpath, linq-to-xml, amazon-mws

I have the following XML from Amazon's Marketplace API. I need to sum all the values of `Item/ItemPrice/Component[type='Principal']/Amount` for all Items to compute an order total. Is this possible to do using LINQ to XML in VB.NET?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
  <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>My Store</MerchantIdentifier>
  </Header>
  <MessageType>OrderReport</MessageType>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OrderReport>
      <AmazonOrderID>050-1234567-1234567</AmazonOrderID>
      <AmazonSessionID>902-1030835-1234567</AmazonSessionID>
      <OrderDate>2002-05-01T15:20:15-08:00</OrderDate>
      <OrderPostedDate>2002-05-01T15:21:49-08:00</OrderPostedDate>
      <BillingData>
        <BuyerEmailAddress>joesmith@hotmail.com</BuyerEmailAddress>
        <BuyerName>Joe Smith</BuyerName>
        <BuyerPhoneNumber>206-555-1234</BuyerPhoneNumber>
      </BillingData>
      <FulfillmentData>
        <FulfillmentMethod>Ship</FulfillmentMethod>
        <FulfillmentServiceLevel>Standard</FulfillmentServiceLevel>
        <Address>
          <Name>Joe Smith</Name>
          <AddressFieldOne>1234 Main St.</AddressFieldOne>
          <City>Seattle</City>
          <StateOrRegion>Washington</StateOrRegion>
          <PostalCode>98004</PostalCode>
          <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
          <PhoneNumber>206-555-1234</PhoneNumber>
        </Address>
      </FulfillmentData>
      <Item>
        <AmazonOrderItemCode>12345678901234</AmazonOrderItemCode>
        <SKU>1234</SKU>
        <Title>Programming Perl, 3rd edition</Title>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <ProductTaxCode>1234</ProductTaxCode>
        <ItemPrice>
          <Component>
            <Type>Principal</Type>
            <Amount currency="USD">10.00</Amount>
          </Component>
          <Component>
            <Type>Shipping</Type>
            <Amount currency="USD">3.49</Amount>
          </Component>
          <Component>
            <Type>Tax</Type>
            <Amount currency="USD">1.29</Amount>
          </Component>
          <Component>
            <Type>ShippingTax</Type>
            <Amount currency="USD">0.24</Amount>
          </Component>
        </ItemPrice>
        <ItemFees>
          <Fee>
            <Type>Commission</Type>
            <Amount currency="USD">-0.75</Amount>
          </Fee>
        </ItemFees>
        <ItemTaxData>
          <TaxJurisdictions>
            <TaxLocationCode>12345678</TaxLocationCode>
            <City>Seattle</City>
            <County>King</County>
            <State>WA</State>
          </TaxJurisdictions>
          <TaxableAmounts>
            <District currency="USD">10.00</District>
            <City currency="USD">10.00</City>
            <County currency="USD">0.00</County>
            <State currency="USD">10.00</State>
          </TaxableAmounts>
          <NonTaxableAmounts>
            <District currency="USD">0.00</District>
            <City currency="USD">0.00</City>
            <County currency="USD">10.00</County>
            <State currency="USD">0.00</State>
          </NonTaxableAmounts>
          <ZeroRatedAmounts>
            <District currency="USD">0.00</District>
            <City currency="USD">0.00</City>
            <County currency="USD">0.00</County>
            <State currency="USD">0.00</State>
          </ZeroRatedAmounts>
          <TaxCollectedAmounts>
            <District currency="USD">0.23</District>
            <City currency="USD">0.53</City>
            <County currency="USD">0.00</County>
            <State currency="USD">0.53</State>
          </TaxCollectedAmounts>
          <TaxRates>
            <District>0.0230</District>
            <City>0.0530</City>
            <County>0.0230</County>
            <State>0.0530</State>
          </TaxRates>
        </ItemTaxData>
        <ShippingTaxData>
          <TaxJurisdictions>
            <TaxLocationCode>12345678</TaxLocationCode>
            <City>Seattle</City>
            <County>King</County>
            <State>WA</State>
          </TaxJurisdictions>
          <TaxableAmounts>
            <District currency="USD">3.49</District>
            <City currency="USD">3.49</City>
            <County currency="USD">0.00</County>
            <State currency="USD">3.49</State>
          </TaxableAmounts>
          <NonTaxableAmounts>
            <District currency="USD">0.00</District>
            <City currency="USD">0.00</City>
            <County currency="USD">3.49</County>
            <State currency="USD">0.00</State>
          </NonTaxableAmounts>
          <ZeroRatedAmounts>
            <District currency="USD">0.00</District>
            <City currency="USD">0.00</City>
            <County currency="USD">0.00</County>
            <State currency="USD">0.00</State>
          </ZeroRatedAmounts>
          <TaxCollectedAmounts>
            <District currency="USD">0.04</District>
            <City currency="USD">0.10</City>
            <County currency="USD">0.00</County>
            <State currency="USD">0.10</State>
          </TaxCollectedAmounts>
          <TaxRates>
            <District>0.0120</District>
            <City>0.0190</City>
            <County>0.0190</County>
            <State>0.0190</State>
          </TaxRates>
        </ShippingTaxData>
        <Promotion>
          <PromotionClaimCode>ABC123</PromotionClaimCode>
          <MerchantPromotionID>12345678</MerchantPromotionID>
          <Component>
            <Type>Principal</Type>
            <Amount currency="USD">-1.00</Amount>
          </Component>
        </Promotion>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <AmazonOrderItemCode>12345678901235</AmazonOrderItemCode>
        <SKU>1234</SKU>
        <Title>Programming ASP.NET, 2nd edition</Title>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <ProductTaxCode>1234</ProductTaxCode>
        <ItemPrice>
          <Component>
            <Type>Principal</Type>
            <Amount currency="USD">12.00</Amount>
          </Component>
          <Component>
            <Type>Shipping</Type>
            <Amount currency="USD">3.49</Amount>
          </Component>
          <Component>
            <Type>Tax</Type>
            <Amount currency="USD">1.42</Amount>
          </Component>
          <Component>
            <Type>ShippingTax</Type>
            <Amount currency="USD">0.24</Amount>
          </Component>
        </ItemPrice>
        <ItemFees>
          <Fee>
            <Type>Commission</Type>
            <Amount currency="USD">-0.75</Amount>
          </Fee>
        </ItemFees>
        <ItemTaxData>
          <TaxJurisdictions>
            <TaxLocationCode>12345678</TaxLocationCode>
            <City>Seattle</City>
            <County>King</County>
            <State>WA</State>
          </TaxJurisdictions>
          <TaxableAmounts>
            <District currency="USD">10.00</District>
            <City currency="USD">10.00</City>
            <County currency="USD">0.00</County>
            <State currency="USD">10.00</State>
          </TaxableAmounts>
          <NonTaxableAmounts>
            <District currency="USD">0.00</District>
            <City currency="USD">0.00</City>
            <County currency="USD">10.00</County>
            <State currency="USD">0.00</State>
          </NonTaxableAmounts>
          <ZeroRatedAmounts>
            <District currency="USD">0.00</District>
            <City currency="USD">0.00</City>
            <County currency="USD">0.00</County>
            <State currency="USD">0.00</State>
          </ZeroRatedAmounts>
          <TaxCollectedAmounts>
            <District currency="USD">0.23</District>
            <City currency="USD">0.53</City>
            <County currency="USD">0.00</County>
            <State currency="USD">0.53</State>
          </TaxCollectedAmounts>
          <TaxRates>
            <District>0.0230</District>
            <City>0.0530</City>
            <County>0.0230</County>
            <State>0.0530</State>
          </TaxRates>
        </ItemTaxData>
        <ShippingTaxData>
          <TaxJurisdictions>
            <TaxLocationCode>12345678</TaxLocationCode>
            <City>Seattle</City>
            <County>King</County>
            <State>WA</State>
          </TaxJurisdictions>
          <TaxableAmounts>
            <District currency="USD">3.49</District>
            <City currency="USD">3.49</City>
            <County currency="USD">0.00</County>
            <State currency="USD">3.49</State>
          </TaxableAmounts>
          <NonTaxableAmounts>
            <District currency="USD">0.00</District>
            <City currency="USD">0.00</City>
            <County currency="USD">3.49</County>
            <State currency="USD">0.00</State>
          </NonTaxableAmounts>
          <ZeroRatedAmounts>
            <District currency="USD">0.00</District>
            <City currency="USD">0.00</City>
            <County currency="USD">0.00</County>
            <State currency="USD">0.00</State>
          </ZeroRatedAmounts>
          <TaxCollectedAmounts>
            <District currency="USD">0.04</District>
            <City currency="USD">0.10</City>
            <County currency="USD">0.00</County>
            <State currency="USD">0.10</State>
          </TaxCollectedAmounts>
          <TaxRates>
            <District>0.0120</District>
            <City>0.0190</City>
            <County>0.0190</County>
            <State>0.0190</State>
          </TaxRates>
        </ShippingTaxData>
        <Promotion>
          <PromotionClaimCode>ABC123</PromotionClaimCode>
          <MerchantPromotionID>12345678</MerchantPromotionID>
          <Component>
            <Type>Principal</Type>
            <Amount currency="USD">-1.00</Amount>
          </Component>
        </Promotion>
      </Item>
    </OrderReport>
  </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Comment: Check my answer for one liner XPath expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you'd solve this in VB using the more idomatic inline-XML with Linq syntax.

```
Dim result =
   From xcmp In azm...<Item>.<ItemPrice>.<Component>
   Where xcmp.<Type>.Value = "Principal"
   Select Convert.ToDecimal(xcmp.<Amount>.Value)

Console.WriteLine(result.Sum().ToString())
```

The triple dot syntax is for descendant searches.  The single dot syntax moves to the child node.  The `azm` variable is an XDocument holding your XML.

Comment: Best answer so far! I love the axis operators in VB10

Answer (score 1):

Here's the c# version that would work

```
XDocument d = XDocument.Load(xmlFileName);
var sum = d.Root.Descendants("Item").Where(i => i.Element("ItemPrice")
                                                 .Element("Component")
                                                 .Element("Type")
                                                 .Value == "Principal")
                                    .Sum(i => Convert.ToDouble(i.Element("ItemPrice")
                                                               .Element("Component")
                                                               .Element("Amount")
                                                               .Value));
```

See if you can use a converter such as http://converter.telerik.com/ to convert to vb.net to use it.

Here's what I got from automatic conversion.

```
Dim d As XDocument = XDocument.Load(xmlFileName)
Dim sum = d.Root.Descendants("Item").Where(Function(i) i.Element("ItemPrice").Element("Component").Element("Type").Value = "Principal").Sum(Function(i) Convert.ToDouble(i.Element("ItemPrice").Element("Component").Element("Amount").Value))
```

EDIT:

Switched from `Convert.ToInt64()` to `Convert.ToDouble()`.

Comment: The questioner was asking for VB, and the syntax of this answer is poor compared to the more idomatic Linq given by hermiod.  Congrats on getting the answer anyway.  Speed over accuracy wins on this site I suppose, but as a VB dev I much prefer seeing VB questions here get real VB answers.

Comment: @mattmc3 the thing with hermiod's answer is that he starts with Descendants("Component") which could be wrong as the OP has specifically mentioned a path to use. There could be a Component tag inside of a non "item" item tag which his answer would pick up. I was just trying to be specific to the question.

Comment: I'm a c# developer and I'm not familiar with VB syntax but I know the concept is similar. I don't have to give an answer that the OP can copy and paste and expect it to work. The c# syntax has been formatted well to give the OP a hint and there are converters out there that do a decent job if you have trouble.

Comment: I do a whole lot of C# myself and I don't expect anyone to give a copy-and-paste answer. But I see this as a teaching site, and Linq to XML is one of those places where C# and VB.NET were not created equal and a native VB.NET speaker would better serve the instructive needs of answering the question.  That having been said, I certainly respect your rep and your working solution... just asking for a little care towards being sure that this stays an instructive site, because a quick answer helps the asker in the short term, but the google hits last forever.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
    Dim foo As List(Of Decimal) = (From i In xmlstring.Descendants("Component")
                                   Where i.Parent.Name = "ItemPrice"
                                   Where i.Element("Type") = "Principal"
                                   Select Convert.ToDecimal(i.Element("Amount").Value)).ToList()

    Dim result = foo.Sum()
```

xmlstring variable is the xdocument.

Comment: This produces a sum of 20D, not 22D.

Comment: Have fixed it now, didn't see the additional nodes under <Promotion> which matched my where condition.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to sum all the values of
>   `Item/ItemPrice/Component[type='Principal']/Amount`
>   for all Items to compute an order
>   total.

This XPath expression:

```
sum(
  /AmazonEnvelope
    /Message
      /OrderReport
        /Item
          /ItemPrice
            /Component[Type='Principal']
              /Amount
)
```

Result: `22`

Comment: @Mark for XPath, you can do (sorry, again c#) 

`XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(xmlFileName);
    XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
    XPathExpression expr = nav.Compile("sum(/AmazonEnvelope/Message/OrderReport/Item/ItemPrice/Component[Type='Principal']/Amount)");
    double total = (double) nav.Evaluate(expr);`

Comment: @Mark But I thought you specifically wanted a linq-to-xml solution.