# vb.net triple dot syntax for linq to xml

Tags: c#, vb.net, syntax

I ran into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875015/linq-to-xml-sum-child-nodes-in-vb-net/5882777#5882777) which had a triple dot syntax in VB.NET that I have never seen before.

The query looks like this

```
Dim result =
   From xcmp In azm...<Item>.<ItemPrice>.<Component>
   Where xcmp.<Type>.Value = "Principal"
   Select Convert.ToDecimal(xcmp.<Amount>.Value)
```

I tried to search on google about this triple dot syntax but I didn't get anything.

Can someone point to to some documentation about this syntax and I was also wondering it will work with **C#** or if there is an equivalent ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The triple dots is a [“descendant axis”](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384974.aspx) which is used to access a list of XML nodes of a given name in [XML literal syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384460.aspx) (“LINQ to XML”):

> Gets all name elements of the [parent] element, regardless of how deep in the hierarchy they occur.

This syntax doesn’t exist in C#, only in VB (for the moment).

Comment: @TheOtherGuy In VB 9 / Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 8):

When using ... instead of ., you refer not to the direct child `<Item>`, but to any `<Item>` in the hierarchy tree.

So `<A>...<B>` give a result for

```
<A>
  <X1>
    <X2>
      <B></B>
   </X2>
  </X1>
</A>
```

whereas `<A>.<B>` would give no result in this example...

Comment: I've never actually seen this syntax myself. Can you confirm that it's equivalent to the XPath selector //Item in this example?

Comment: thanks +1 for example but the other answer addresses my question precisely.

Answer (score 4):

The answer you're referring to was mine from another question, and the triple dot is just a shortcut for calling `.Descendants()`.  C# doesn't support inline XML, so you'll have to call the methods unless you're in VB.  Here's the mapping:

- VB.NET shortcut := C# method
- `...<node>` := `.Descendants("node")`
- `.<node>` := `.Elements("node")`
- `.@attr` := `.Attribute("attr").Value`

You can see all of these from VB's intellisense.

[image: VB.NET intellisense]